# Conditional formatting problems excel

Tags: excel, date, colors, formatting, conditional-statements

Im with a problem here, and i can't solve it

I have a cell with today's date and 2 columns, the first one with a range date (20-mar-15, for example)
the second one with a specific date, that may not be defined yet, in this case, the cell will remain blank

That being said, I want to make the cells in the first column change the colors as the range date is aproaching, like green if 30 days ahead, yellow if 15 days, red if 5 days. But ONLY if the second column remains blank. If there is a specific date in the second column, i dont want the first one to change the colors.

In the formatting rule I tried using this: 
=IF(ISBLANK($AQ$13),$AP13-$E$7<5,FALSE)
if the second one(AQ13) is blank, the function would return the date comparison, if not, would return false

Can someone help me ?

Comment: The formula in your post looks OK, so there's probably something wrong with the source cells. Does the formula give correct results, when you test it in any cell (not conditional formatting)?

Comment: I tried to put this formula in the "Use a formula do determine which cells to format" and it said that the formula contains an error.

The specific date will be posted somewhere between today's date and the specific date.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your formula might be resulting in a negative number. Please can you check if the result of this $AP13-$E$7 is -29. Assuming you are using 20-Mar-2015.

if so please can you try and rewrite as $E$7-$AP13